# MDX - Count(.children) > 0, but .FirstChild.Name is blank

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I'm trying to create a calculated member that returns a string of the value when there is only one distinct child, "Multi" when there are is more than one distinct child, and "None" when there are no children.
Specifically, I'm having trouble returning the case where there is on distinct child name. Here is my calculated measure:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[SSN] AS
  CASE
    WHEN DISTINCTCOUNT([Item].[Season Code Name].Children) = 0
        Then 'None'
    WHEN DISTINCTCOUNT([Item].[Season Code Name].Children) = 1
        Then [Item].[Season Code Name].FirstChild.Name   --.Value is null
    ELSE
        'Multi'
  END
```

The else returns a blank, but if I use [Item].[Season Code Name] in the crossjoin, the children show up as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: OK...  I thought that the following worked.  But, it turned out that this just gives me the first value in the dimension, not the first child of the current member.  Hrmph!:  [Item].[Season Code Name].Children.Item(1).Name

Answer (score 2):

This is a classical, I do that all the times :-), missing **currentMember** after the hierarchy.

```
 WITH MEMBER [Measures].[SSN] AS
  CASE
 WHEN DISTINCTCOUNT([Item].[Season Code Name].currentmember.Children() ) = 0
    Then 'None'
 WHEN DISTINCTCOUNT([Item].[Season Code Name].currentmember.Children() ) = 1
    Then [Item].[Season Code Name].currentmember.FirstChild.Name   --.Value is null
 ELSE
    'Multi'
 END
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do it.  I should note that looking at this from a hierarchy perspective, you can think of the currentmember being at the brand of bike level, while the season code name is like a color on a specific model.  I want the color associated with the first model.  Hope I'm explaining this well.

Comment: I wasn't clear.  The suggested change gives the same result on = 1 - Null

Comment: It's working for me using 'name' property (ok I checked with icCube OLAP Server, but it's very,very like SSAS). Value it's a bit special can you try evaluating the tuple ? "Then ([Item].[Season Code Name].currentmember.FirstChild, Measures.defaultmember)" ?